# How to perform raster calculation (e.g. aspect) on subset of raster based on point intersection in R

Tags: r, optimization, r-raster

I'm working with some raster data in R using the `raster` package. I want to calculate and extract some geographic information (e.g., slope, aspect) from the raster, but only at specific points (I also have some data as a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` at which I want to calculate slope/aspect/etc.). I'm doing this for several high-resolution rasters, and it seems like a poor use of resources to calculate this for every raster cell when I only need maybe 5-10% of them.

I thought maybe the `raster::stackApply` function might work,  but that seems to perform calculations on subsets of a rasterBrick rather than calculations on subsets of a single raster based on point locations (please correct me if I'm wrong). I also thought I could do a for loop, where I extract the surrounding cells nearest each point of interest, and iteratively calculate slope/aspect that way. That seems clunky, and I was hoping for a more elegant or built-in solution, but it should work.

These are my thoughts so far on the for loop, but I'm not sure how best to even do this.

```r
# Attach packages
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# Generate example raster data
r = raster()
set.seed(0)
values(r) = runif(ncell(r), min = 0, max = 1000)

# Generate example point data
df.sp = SpatialPoints(
  coords = cbind(runif(25, min = -100, max = 100),  
                 runif(25, min = -50, max = 50)), 
  proj4string = crs(r))

# Iterate on each row of SpatialPoints
for (i in 1:nrow(df.sp)) {

  # Find cell index of current SpatialPoint
  cell.idx = raster::extract(r, df.sp[i,], cellnumbers = TRUE)[1]

  # Find indices of cells surrounding point of interest
  neighbors.idx = raster::adjacent(r, cell.idx, directions = 16)

  # Get DEM values for cell and surrounding cells
  vals.local = r[c(cell.idx, neighbors.idx[,2])]

  # Somehow convert this back to an appropriate georeferenced matrix
  #r.local = ...

  # Perform geometric calculations on local raster
  #r.stack = terrain(r.local, opt = c('slope', 'aspect'))

  # Remaining data extraction, etc. (I can take it from here...)
}
```

In summary, I need a method to calculate slope and aspect from a DEM raster only at specific points as given by a SpatialPoints object. If you know of a pre-built or more elegant solution, great! If not, some help finishing the for loop (how to best extract a neighborhood of surrounding cells and run calculations on that) would be most appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is a possible approach.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster()
set.seed(0)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), min = 0, max = 1000)
coords <- cbind(runif(25, min = -100, max = 100),  
               runif(25, min = -50, max = 50))

x <- rasterize(coords, r)
f <- focal(x, w=matrix(1, nc=3, nr=3), na.rm=TRUE)             
rr <- mask(r, f)
slope <- terrain(rr, "slope")

extract(slope, coords)
# [1] 0.0019366236 0.0020670699 0.0006305257 0.0025334280 0.0023480935 0.0007527267 0.0002699272 0.0004699626
# [9] 0.0004869054 0.0025651333 0.0010415805 0.0008574920 0.0010664869 0.0017700297 0.0001666226 0.0008405391
#[17] 0.0017682167 0.0009854172 0.0015350466 0.0017714466 0.0012994945 0.0016563132 0.0003276584 0.0020499529
#[25] 0.0006582073
```

Probably not much efficiency gain, as it still processes all the `NA` values

So maybe like this, more along your line of thinking:

```
cells <- cellFromXY(r, coords)
ngbs <- raster::adjacent(r, cells, pairs=TRUE)

slope <- rep(NA, length(cells))
for (i in 1:length(cells)) {
   ci <- ngbs[ngbs[,1] == cells[i], 2]
   e <- extentFromCells(r, ci)
   x <- crop(r, e)
   slope[i] <- terrain(x, "slope")[5]
}
slope
#[1] 0.0019366236 0.0020670699 0.0006305257 0.0025334280 0.0023480935 0.0007527267 0.0002699272 0.0004699626
#[9] 0.0004869054 0.0025651333 0.0010415805 0.0008574920 0.0010664869 0.0017700297 0.0001666226 0.0008405391
#[17] 0.0017682167 0.0009854172 0.0015350466 0.0017714466 0.0012994945 0.0016563132 0.0003276584 0.0020499529
#[25] 0.0006582073
```

But I find that brute force

```
slope <- terrain(r, "slope")
extract(slope, coords)
```

is fastest, 9x faster than my first alternative and 4 times faster than the second alternative

Comment: You are absolutely right, the brute force method is actually considerably faster for my data set. That quite surprised me, but oh well. What I'll probably do is merge the DEMs into one large one, calculate slope/aspect on that, and then save the resulting outputs for later use to save on later processing. Thanks for your help and thoughts on it though!